# Starting process from another process crashes

Tags: c#, wpf

i have problem while i'm trying to start app from another app which start from another app.
I got 3 aplications: A,B,C
i can run A just like that, but albo i can also run A from B, which works only when i start B from cmd.
But i also have my Menu application ( "C" ), which can start diffrent applications: A or B or other 3.
And my problem starts when i want to start app "A" from app "B" which started from my menu ( app "C").

in few words:

**B** => **A**  -- Works

**C** => **B** => **A** -- Crashes when trying to run A.

I tried to think why it happens, and couldn't even know what should i google to find solution.

How i Start "B" from "C"

```
private void StartApp()
        {
            Process.Start("Aps\\B\\B.exe", "/nologin passthrough");
        }
```

and Same for App "A" from "B"

```
private void UserControl_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    Process.Start("A.exe",
      string.Format("/machine {0} /multi",_laneName));
}
```

Comment: Do you get an exception?

Comment: On face value theres no reason it should fail - what actual errors does it produce?

Comment: no, i didn't, only got Windows dialog that told me i can find files which can help describe problem:
C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\WER10A4.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml
  C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\WER1C68.tmp.appcompat.txt
  C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\WER1D63.tmp.mdmp

Comment: But those file have only information about my applications etc

Comment: well in b, you call a.. but you're calling it from b's location - in c, you call b, which calls a, but this time it will be in C's location...

Comment: Why should it open from C's location? I thought it should be like another process which has nothing to do with "C" app

Comment: You arent telling the process to start from somewhere else, so its starts from its "current" location.

Comment: yes, but when i start B from cmd and than A, it should have same current location like when i start C = > B and than A.

Comment: A and B are in same directory

Comment: U are right, i checked it and it has previous directory, but how can get actual "current" directory of this file?